# WKWebView web inspector in macOS app fails to render and flickers/flashes

Tags: javascript, swift, macos, wkwebview, web-inspector

I have enabled developer extras for my WKWebView, but when I select "Inspect Element" from the dropdown, the inspector does not render properly.  It's basically transparent, and the bottom half of the web view flickers and flashes, but no inspector content ever appears.

I *can* resize the window to be too small for the inspector, and then when I Inspect Element the inspector appears as an external window, and everything works properly.  However, adding a window-resize/invoke-inspector/window-resize to every test cycle in rather painful.

Acceptable answers may include:

1. Any way to fix the flickering in the WKWebView internal inspector,
2. Swift/Objective-C code for invoking the external inspector window programmatically,
3. JavaScript code for invoking the external inspector window programmatically

... or any other ideas for how to tackle this.

Seen under 10.14 (Mojave) and 10.15 (Catalina).  Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: More information needed — does it do this when inspecting all web content? What about Safari's inspector? Did you try a vanilla, unconfigured WKWebView to see if the behavior persists? Did you try placing it in a different window, in a vanilla project?

Comment: I tried a vanilla project, and had the exact same problem, for all content (even a static HTML string, no JS content).  And then on a whim, tried it in that project without constraints.  Works great.  Disabled autolayout for that view, added springs and struts, and everything works fine (whether the inspector appears internally or externally).  And now my project is fixed.   I might not have tried that in my project without your suggestion, so thank you, @mattsven.

Comment: Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue appears to be with using constraints on a WKWebView.  If you have an autolayout view and a WKWebView, turning off constraints fixes the inspector rendering.  In my app, the UI is just a big browser window, so I could turn off autolayout for the view, add springs and struts, and everything renders properly.

I hate answering my own question, but...

Comment: THANKS!! And please accept your answer so it's easier to find ;-) It should also be noted that you can also wrap the webview into another NSView to preserve auto layout capabilities

Comment: Thanks! For everyone else who has forgotten how to do this: Add a wrapper view with constraints, add the WKWebView as the wrapper’s subview without constraints, set the WKWebView’s `frame` to match the wrapper view’s `bounds`, then set the `webView.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]` and `wrapperView.autoresizesSubviews = true`

Comment: This had been driving me up the wall on and off for ages! Thanks!

Comment: This also fixes a lesser issue where a WKWebView in a split view would stutter when the sidebar pane was collapsed or expanded.